# How to change the value of a data-cycle in jQuery Cycle2 plugin when I get to a specific element on a page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2

I have a jQuery Cycle2 on [this page](http://cleverwitz.com/dev/). Using data-cycle-paused="true" I am able to pause the slideshow indefinitely.

What I need to do is change data-cycle-paused="true" to data-cycle-paused="false" when the user gets to that point on the page so the animation begins.

I have searched the API documentation as well as numerous other sources and I can't find anything about making that kind of a change to trigger the slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found following solution in [documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/).
Second one from behind in `Commands` section.

resume - Resumes a paused slideshow.

```
$('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('resume');
```

Hope it was what you were looking for.

Edit:
Try following solution, note that **it will work only for first one**) slideshow on your site:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var animatedElement = document.getElementsByClassName('cycle-slideshow')[0],
        animatedElementPosition = animatedElement.offsetTop,
        animatedElementHeight = animatedElement.offsetHeight,
        currentScrollPosition = window.pageYOffset,
        resumed = false;

    if( (currentScrollPosition >= animatedElementPosition) &&
        (currentScrollPosition <= animatedElementPosition + animatedElementHeight ) ){
        if(!resumed){
            $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('resume');
            resumed = true;
        }
    } else {
        if(resumed){
            $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('pause');
            resumed = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Edit 2: When I run script on your website I got following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).cycle is not a function
```

Which probably means, that there is problem due to jQuery isn't included **once**, but more.

Yes it is, in your html:

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you are **sure** that **removing** the second one won't take impact on your website features eg. **another plugins may require** this **older** version of **jquery**, then **remove it**! :) Should work.

P.S. Notice that when you scroll down to up, your animation will appear faster then it should, because "cycle-slideshow" height is much bigger than image I could see.

Comment: Hi Garrett, what would be the best way to trigger that?

Comment: Hi Garrett, apologies for the delay - I was out yesterday. I implemented the code. It is in place now, but it isn't triggering correctly. I also can't find a duplicate of jQuery. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: @fmz I have no idea how, but it seems you have 2x jQuery. Hit `F12` in your browser and `Ctrl+F` then type `jquery` and you will see following lines, as I described above. Just try to comment line with this jQuery you have in your code and see what happens. Probably something 3rd party includes jQuery too.

Comment: I commented out the 1.11.3 version and now the slider is broken. I can't find jquery 2.0.3 even with a search of the source code.

Comment: @fmz Try paste this
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`
and for now still 1.11.3 leave commented.

Comment: FOUND. `dev/CleverWitz_home_animation_edge.js` includes second jQuery.

Comment: Well done. Sharp eyes. I removed the other instance of jQuery. Please take a look. jQuery cycle doesn't seem to recognize the 2.0.3 instance. BTW, thank you for your help on this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77341/discussion-between-garrett-and-fmz).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an event handler for the `scroll` event (https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) and in it use any method  of detecting whether your slideshow appears into view from here: [Check if element is visible after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

Upon detecting appearance just do

```
$('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('resume');
```